# Angular Cli Install

Tags: windows, angular-cli

Why when I install globally Angular CLI using command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli
```

with the version of the packages also appears the text

> (cli-only)

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Is there a problem related to that?

Comment: Thanks @R.Richards, I am new to angular and I am following the tutorial: https://www.zeolearn.com/magazine/setup-angular-windows and when the ng version command is run the text (cli-only) does not appear.

Comment: You're running `ng version` while in the `C:\Windows\system32` directory. There isn't an angular project there. Run the command while in a directory where there is an angular project, and you will see different output. Consider finding a tutorial that is a little less out of date, too. The one you're using is over 1.5 years old.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarifying and for the recommendation. I will look for a more updated tutorial. Greetings